# Core Data: fetch background and using objectWithID on main thread, performance benefit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-data

I read Core Data Programming Guide recently and Apple suggest us to do so

> You fetch in one managed object context on a background thread, and pass the object IDs of the fetched 
>   objects to another thread. In the second thread (typically the application's main thread, so that you can 
>   then display the results), you use the second context to fault in objects with those object IDs (you use 
>   objectWithID: to instantiate the object). (This technique is only useful if you are using an SQLite store, > since data from binary and XML stores is read into memory immediately on open.)

To my understanding, fetch on background context will not register the managed object in main thread context, so the managed object returned from objectWithID is most likely a fault. When we using it on main thread, we will trigger a new round of trip to the SQLite Store. So the UI maybe blocked.

Did I miss anything ? Are there a way to avoid I/O overhead on main thread ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much overheard when you do a fetch in the background and then use the objectID to do a fetch on the main thread. First, the record will be on the CoreData cache, which makes the same fetch on the main thread faster, and second, fetching with an objectID is much much much faster than fetching with your average fetch request. What you usually do is that you would create a background fetch request, find the objectID of the objects you are looking for, and move those objectIDs to the main thread. Of course, for the background thread, you have to use a different NSManagedObjectContext instance than the main thread one.

I would recommend you to check the WWDC 2010 video "Mastering Core Data". It goes into core data and multithreading, explaining the performance of caching and fetching on the background/main thread.

Comment: I have checked the video and still quite confused. You mentioned "CoreData cache", to my understanding, a Managed Object Context is a cache however it's thread specific. So it will not help here.Apple's documentation mentions "row cache" without any explanation. it seems it's used by all thread and it's persist store specific. Is it the "CoreData Cache"?

Comment: Yes. It's a cache related to the persistent store, not the managed object context.

Comment: Are there any official documentation about the row cache? How did you guys figure this out?

Comment: Apple has mentioned the row cache on several of their documentation and videos, but they do not provide documentation to this because you do not have access to the cached information. Basically, this happens in the background, and when you fetch, you get the data either from the cache or from the persistent store, but the way this works is transparent to you.

Comment: I have to say Apple's documentation is quite vague. Why there is a down vote to your answer?

Comment: No idea. At that moment I received I received several down votes on other answers as well. Maybe someone didn't like me.